# How to check if a specific textbox under a specific div is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<PlaceHolder>
<div class="greenDiv">
  <asp:TextBox ID="a"  runat="server" />
</div>
<div  class="greenDiv">
  <asp:TextBox ID="ab" runat="server" />
</div>
</PlaceHolder>
```

I need to let the user know if he left a Textbox empty, I tried something like this.. (not working) What have I missed?

```
 $('.greenDiv > input:text').blur(function () {
   if (!$(this).val()) {
     alert("fill this field");
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `input[type=text]` instead

```
$('.greenDiv>input[type=text]').blur(function () {
    if (!$.trim($(this).val())) {
        alert("fill this field");
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work.. I add it in the  $(document).ready() function.. is it matters ?

Comment: No, It can be added in `ready()`. Did you add jQuery. Please check your console to see any error occurred!

Comment: Careful with spaces and invisible characters. I know you've accepted this answer already, but look at mine anyways.

Comment: Thank you, I will use your answer also :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.greenDiv > input[type=text]').on('blur', function (e) {
  if (!$(e.currentTarget).val()) alert('fill this field');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `input:text` you should use  `input[type=text]`

```js
$('.greenDiv>input[type=text]').on("blur",function () {
                if (!$(this).val()) {
                    alert("fill this field");
                }
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="greenDiv">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="greenDiv">
  <input type="text">
 
</div>
```

Comment: the textboxes are in two different divs with the same class = "greenDiv" each div - one textbox

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <PlaceHolder>
<div class="greenDiv">
  <asp:TextBox ID="a" class="x"  runat="server" />
</div>
<div  class="greenDiv">
  <asp:TextBox ID="ab" class="x" runat="server" />
</div>
</PlaceHolder>
```

below is Jquery

```
 $('.greenDiv .x').blur(function () {
                if (!$(this).val()) {
                    alert("fill this field");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.greenDiv > input:text').blur(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) === '') {
        alert("fill this field");
    }
});
```

Your selector is fine. When you use `!$(this).val()` you allow inputs with spaces (or any other invisible character) to fall through. An input with a single space is technically not empty. Try `$.trim(something) === ''` instead.